# Convert data from SQL Server database into JSON format using python

Tags: json, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert data from SQL Server database into JSON format using python. I'm getting some error:

> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
>    TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable

Here is my code:

```
    import pyodbc
    import json


    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=localhost;'
                          'Database=testDb;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    qa = cursor.execute('select * from dbo.sample where id = 1 FOR JSON PATH').fetchall()

    for row in qa:
         test = json.dumps(qa)
         print (test)
```

Can someone correct me what am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert Row object to list btw you meant `dumps(row)` not `dumps(qa)` right?

```
for row in qa:
     test = json.dumps([x for x in row])
     print (test)
```